# How do I correctly pass credentials to a remote instance of ActiveMQ using the HTTP protocol?

Tags: spring, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

as of now I have the following class in java:

```
public class CamelActivemqExampleUsingSpring {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);
        try {
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            } finally {
            camelContext.stop();
            }
    }
}
```

and the following xml for applicationContent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       ">
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="http://urlwheremyactivemqishosted" />
        <property name="userName" value="un" />
        <property name="password" value="pw" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file://src/test/resources/TestMessages" />
            <to uri="activemq:queue:test" />
        </route>

    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

The username and password are filled in with the correct credentials as is the brokerURL. However, whenever I try to run the java code, it says that

Failed to perform GET on: http:urlmyactivemqisat as response was: Unauthorized

So, I'm pretty sure I'm trying to pass the credentials correctly but I can't figure out how to do it. I've googled around but a lot of the results were not that relevant. It seems most people using camel and activemq have locally hosted test instances of activemq and are using vm or tcp. That or they are not sending JMS to a queue but are listening to a queue to consume jms.

Comment: Usually broker URL uses the tcp or nio protocol not http. Does changing that make a difference?

Comment: Yeah I noticed while troubleshooting that most other users were using really anything other than http. Unfortunately as a tester I don't have control over our activemq, which is hosted as http. Trying to set the brokerurl as a different protocol causes a different error, which says something along the lines of "cannot send, channel has already failed."

Comment: If you are using the HTTP/HTTPS support enabled on a remote instance of ActiveMQ. then all the configuration that you've added is not required as it's only needed for other transports like nio, tcp. In this case you'll just need a httpClient, here's some good test-cases from ActiveMQ source to give greater illustration. http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.8.0/testapidocs/src-html/org/apache/activemq/web/RestTest.html

Comment: @AshokNanda oh wow.. I've spent a week stuck trying to figure out how to use camel and HTTP to send messages to activemq and was getting frustrated because I couldn't find anyone else who had tried that yet so it was really difficult to find resources. Now I realize no one's tried it because everyone else was just using Rest and I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help, ended up setting up what i needed using okhttp.